# 68K Assembly Output and Array

Tags: arrays, assembly, motorola

I am trying to figure out how to print out something from an array in Motorola 68K.

My array is going to contain week days, 'Sunday.,Monday.,Tuesday.*_*_,'This going all the way to Saturday with the size field as 12.

As far as arrays, I know that you must multiple the array index by the size field, then add that to the array address. (Please correct me if I am wrong) After that I should be able to get Sunday, or some other day.

As of now, I have in storage dec Answer: 'The Day Is' and in the coding area Lineout Answer, which would simply spit out, The Day Is. Now my question is, how do I lineout so that it will read The Day is Wednesday(Or whatever day it's supposed to be)

Comment: I haven't managed to understand your problem and what you are trying to get done. Could you describe in a bit more detail?

Comment: "As far as arrays, I know that you must multiple the array index by the size field, then add that to the array address." - That depends...  Auto increment increments the address by the size of your access. word access -> increment by one word (not one byte).

Comment: Hey @turboscrew, thanks for the help so far. I have an algorithm to get the array index and I have stored it into D1. Which then I multiplied it by 12(my size field) (Mulu #12,D1) As for the array address I'm not sure what that is

Comment: To continue. My storage declaration has . 7 things labled arrays. Example, array: dc.b 'Sunday_____',0 array1: dc.b 'Monday____',0 and so on. (The underscores are just to show I've made enough space for the size fields to all equal up.) Should I do move.l array,A0, move.l array1,A1, and so on. Then adda D1 to A0? Assuming this is correct should I have an output of Monday, or Tuesday?

Comment: You could do that (but remember the end null after string) or you could make a pointer array to the strings, but that would add one indirection. Array address is the address of the first element of the array - just like in C (or C has it just like in assembly). In other words: the label before the string.